# How Watch UINT64 Array as ASCII in .NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I need to debug an array of many elements (all of them are UINT64) in WATCH window of Visual Studio 2013.

I can view them separately using:

```
  System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Element(0)))
```

This code show me 8 ASCII bytes in WATCH window. For instance:

```
    UINT64 = 7016996765293437281 shows me 'aaaaaaaa'  (what I need!)
```

I wonder if I would have any way to see the entire UINT64 array as ASCII characters using just a single instruction.

I search this in MSDN and all samples show a manual conversion in FOREACH-NEXT loop.

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide an example of your data.

Comment: What is the gain in viewing UInt64 values as ASCII characters? Just use the quick watch or the watch window for the entire array, right click any of the values and TICK "Hexadecimal display"

Comment: Better yet, under the Debug/Windows open a memory window, and paste the name of your array variable (Element I assume) there. It will show you all the elements in one shot with their ASCII equivalents

Comment: No, I don´t want to see HEX values... If so, I would have done this, obviously. I need to check the entire array as ASCII and I only need to know if it is possible.

Comment: Memory window shows the ASCII values too.

Comment: Steve, my data is a lot of UINT64 values in an array - I don´t need to update these values to know if is there a possible to see them as ASCII in debug/watch window, isn't it?

Comment: @OguzOzgul, I don´t see MEMORY WINDOW in my Debug/Windows options! I´m using VB.NET in VS2013.

Comment: You need to provide an example of your data.   And how you want to see it in the debugger window.

Comment: Steve, for instance:  UINT64 = 7016996765293437281 and its ASCII is 'aaaaaaaa'

Comment: The memory windows should be available when you are running your application and stop on a breakpoint.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, thanks but I´m not seeing this option in my Debug/Windows options, even stoped in a breakpoint. Shouldn't this there specific for C++ or C# ?

Comment: You said you had an array....sigh.....I'm done here.   Good luck.

Comment: I can see the Memory windows for a VB application here. It does not show the memory location for the array however..

Comment: Thanks @SteveWellens. Yes, I have an ARRAY OF UINT64 VALUES. This is pointed into the question. You asked me for a sample and I gave one.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have these namespaces included:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

Now, try this expression:

```
string.Concat(element.Select(e => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(e))))
```

This will display all the elements in your array as a string of ASCII.

**EDIT** Here's one solution without lambda functions that may work in a debug setting:

```
string.Concat(element.Select(BitConverter.GetBytes).Select(Encoding.ASCII.GetString))
```

Comment: But b.ToString() will display uint64 123123 as "123123". That's not what he wants.

Comment: I now see the responses. It's requested in ASCII. The body of the question wasn't clear. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: I just ran the updated response with `var element = new ulong[] { 0x4847464544434241, 0x504F4E4D4C4B4A49, 0x5857565554535251 };` as seed data and it appears to work. I'm inclined to believe this is endian-dependent. This would display `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX`.

Comment: @SaxxonPike, your code is great but in WATCH/DEBUG window I receive "Evaluation of Lambda expression is not valid in the debugger". Good try, I appreciated this.

Comment: Without the use of Linq as such, I'm afraid you won't get a one-line solution.

Comment: @SaxxonPike, unfortunely I have the same answer fro debug´s WATCH window.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include another way that does not involve lambda functions. It's a rather unconventional use for Linq, but it works in regular code.

Comment: Thanks @SaxxonPike, but now I have the following error:   "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetBytes' accepts this number of arguments" - I guess because it´s not a BYTE array but an UINT64 one.

Comment: I used it with a ulong[] which should be equivalent to UInt64[]. Not sure what to tell you now :) Best luck figuring it out!